# $\sigma$-algebra generated by dyadic intervals defines a filtration

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a $\sigma$-algebra defined by $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma\left([(k-1)2^{-n}, k2^{-n}),1 \leq k \leq 2^n \right)$ (the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing those intervals). I now want to prove that this defines a filtration so I think I just have to prove that $\mathcal{F}_{n+1} \supseteq \mathcal{F}_n$ and that it is in fact increasing in $n$.

To do this I think it's enough to show that if some $x \in [(k-1)2^{-n}, k2^{-n})$ for some $1 \leq k \leq 2^n$ then it is contained in a $\pi$-system of $\mathcal{F}_n$ so the only thing left to prove is that $x$ is contained in $[(k-1)2^{-(n+1)}, k2^{-(n+1)})$ for some $1 \leq k \leq 2^{n+1}$ as this is a generating $\pi$-system for $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$.

Do I reason correctly here and if so is there an easy argument that can be made here? And how could I prove that the sequence $\mathcal{F}$ is in fact increasing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't have to show that $x$ is contained in a $\pi$-system (this doesn't make sense at all!), but you have to show that intervals of the form $[(k-1)2^{-n},k 2^{-n})$ are contained in $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_n$ denote the set of intervals generating $F_n$. Then clearly $A_n \subset F_{n+1}$ (because each interval in $A_n$ is the union of two intervals in $A_{n+1}$, and this union is contained in $F_{n+1}$). And so $F_n =\sigma(A_n) \subset \sigma(F_{n+1}) = F_{n+1}$.